# Regular Expressions in ios(a word a letter and special characters)

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

In the below method, I want to check a `UITextField` Text if:
it contains one or more English words, and one or more numbers and let optionally contains special characters(!@$&#)
return true, else return false.

```
#define pattern   @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\u0021\\u0040\\u0023\\u0024\\u0026]{1}*$"

- (BOOL)stringHasCorrectFormat:(NSString *)str {

      if ([str componentsSeparatedByString:SPACE].count > 1)
         return NO;
      NSString *regularPattern = EMPTY_STRING;
      regularPattern = [regularPattern stringByAppendingString:pattern]
      NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:regularPattern
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:nil];



      NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex
                               firstMatchInString:str
                               options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];


     if (match != nil) {
         return YES;
     }

     return NO;
}
```

thanks

Comment: what is your problem? you need only show words or numbers?

Comment: You actually do not allow 0 or more symbols. Use `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\u0021\\u0040\\u0023\\u0024\\u0026]*$"`. If you want to make sure there is a letter and a digit, use `@"^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=\\D*\\d)[a-zA-Z0-9\\u0021\\u0040\\u0023\\u0024\\u0026]*$"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9!@$&#]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- `(?=.*[a-z])` Require the string to contain at least one `a-z` character
- `(?=.*[0-9])` Require the string to contain at least one `0-9` character
- `[a-z0-9!@$&#]*$` Allow the string to be made up of only `a-z` characters, `0-9` characters, and `!@$&#` symbols

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/mC3kL3/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9!&#]*             any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           '!', '&', '#' (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```